# Configure IDs of liquibase changesets

Tags: liquibase, changeset

Is there any way to configure the IDs of liquibase changesets? I mean for example at `id="1528876614155-1"` the first part is autogenerated and the second part is the number of changeset. Is there a way to configure the first part by myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number you have shown is only generated by Liquibase if you do reverse engineering of an existing schema.

So, if your question is: "*Can I change the way Liquibase generates those numbers during reverse engineering?*", then the answer is no (unless you use a different way to generate a changelog from an existing schema). But it shouldn't be a big problem to do a search & replace using a regex to change that number into something else.

If your question is: "*Can I use a different pattern once I start manually adding changesets?*", then the answer is yes: you can add whatever you want for an ID of a changeset. The only limit you have is that it may not exceed 255 characters (as that is the size of the column where this value is stored).